# Sharing Package.swift configuration across Swift packages

Tags: package, swift-package-manager

I have a project with many local Swift packages, and a lot of configuration is repeated across the `Package.swift` manifest files (compiler flags, etc).

Is there a way to share this configuration? Or do we have to wait for the [extensible build tools](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0303-swiftpm-extensible-build-tools.md) in Swift 5.6?